# ajax post without refresh in multiple rows table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am getting $pgcode value required for the second select option but the form is refreshed which I do not want. I also tried adding some html `div`s but in that case the form is duplicating some content and also refreshing.

How can I make this work without a refresh occurring?

```
<?php

if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
    ob_start();
}
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include("dbc.php");

if (isset($_POST['model'])) {
    $pgcode = $_POST['model'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $('#dataTable').on('change','.select-desc',function(){
        var cur_val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"cashtran.php",
            data:{model:cur_val},
            success:function(result){
                $('body').html(result);
                    },

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="top">
<br class="clear" />
<div class="wrapper col4">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <form method="post" name="frmcashtran" action="">
        <h3><span class="orange">Cash Payment Details</span></h3>
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" id="addRow" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Remove Row" id="deleteRow"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="dataTable" border="0">
                <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><label>Main A/c</label></td>
                   <td><label>Subledger</label></td>
                   <td><label>Narration</label></td>
                   <td><label>Amount</label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                       <td>
                       <?php
$sql = "SELECT gcode,acname FROM account ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<select name='acname[]' class='select-desc' tabindex='2'>";
echo "<option value=''>-- Select Main A/c --</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value = '{$row['gcode']}'";
    if ($pgcode == $row['gcode'])
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">{$row['acname']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                       <?php
$sql = "SELECT scode,sname FROM subldg where gcode='$pgcode' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<select name='slname[]'  tabindex='2'>";
echo "<option value=''>-- Select Subledger--</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value = '{$row['scode']}'";
    if ($pscode == $row['scode'])
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">{$row['sname']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
                        </td>
              </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "page" is refreshing because of `$('body').html(result);` This is basically replacing the WHOLE content of the page with whatever the AJAX response is. Change this statement to only update the part of the HTML you want to update, not the whole `<body>`

Comment: i replaced body with one division having id as "result" still my form gets refreshed and some part duplicates and i tried the same with division having class then the code doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

If the entire page is being sent back as the response to the ajax request change the following PHP code

```
if (isset($_POST['model'])) {
    $pgcode = $_POST['model'];
}
```

to

```
if( isset( $_POST['model'] ) ) {
    ob_clean();
    $pgcode = $_POST['model'];
    exit( $pgcode );
}
```

Comment: still facing the same problem..page is getting refreshed